# How to create a document on the legal size pager using Xfinium.PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf, uwp

I'm using Xfinium.PDF cross-platform component (UWP) to create PDF documents. It works great except I'm not able to figure out how to create a legal size PDF document. Whatever I try, the documents come out as a letter size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The legal size is 8.5*14 in (612*1008 pt).

A legal size document can be created if you set the legal size on each page in the document, like in the sample below:

```
PdfFixedDocument document = new PdfFixedDocument();            
PdfPage page = document.Pages.Add();
page.Width = 612;
page.Height = 1008;
document.Save("Sample_Legal.pdf");
```

UPDATE: For PdfFlowDocument you can do this:

```
PdfFlowDocumentDefaults fdd = new PdfFlowDocumentDefaults();
fdd.PageDefaults.Width = 612;
fdd.PageDefaults.Height = 1008;
PdfFlowDocument fd = new PdfFlowDocument(fdd);

// add content to document

fd.Save("Sample_Flow_Legal.pdf");
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops the [XFINIUM.PDF](http://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-crossplatform/xfinium-pdf-features.html) library.

Comment: Thanks Mihai. I'm actually using the PdfFlowDocument, not PdfFixedDocument. For the PdfFlowDocument I did something like this: PdfFlowDocumentDefaults documentDefaults = new PdfFlowDocumentDefaults();
documentDefaults.PageDefaults.Height = 1008;     Do you think this is a good solution?

Comment: @ata6502 yes, it is the recommended solution, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Mihai. This answers my question.

Comment: @ata6502 feel free to mark your question as answered